# Does a matrix represent a bijection

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory, algorithms

We have a square binary matrix that represents a connection from rows to columns. Is there a way to tell if a bijection exists (other than checking for all possible bijections and iterating through them)?

EXAMPLE:

```
1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1
```

ANSWER:

Yes, here is one such bijection.

```
 1 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 
 0 0 0 1
 0 0 1 0
```

Each bijection would also be known as a permutation matrix. I am not interested in what the bijection is, just need to know if it exists.

One solution is to list all bijections for a matrix (there are M! of them) and then check if our matrix "contains" it. I'm not sure if "contains" is even a concept in matrix problems. My problem involves a dense matrix over 100x100.

---

My ultimate motive is to answer "how do you quickly count the number of bijections 'contained' in a matrix" which is just fancy words for an identical combinatorics problem, [Counting permutations, with additional restrictions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509563/counting-permutations-with-additional-restrictions)

Comment: Thanks in advance for any help. I'm interested in any advice even if you can't answer the question completely.

Comment: If you consider the matrix as representing a graph, your problem is called **perfect matching**.  There are efficient polynomial-time algorithms for finding a perfect matching if one exists. Counting all the perfect matchings may be much harder, however; I don't know.  One thing to look into: it's possible that there is an efficient way to calculate the so-called [matching polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_polynomial).

Comment: Counting perfect matchings is NP-hard ($\#$P-complete to be precise).

Comment: Possibly useful: [Counting Perfect Matchings as Fast as Ryser](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.4466) “We show that there is a polynomial space algorithm that counts the number of perfect matchings in an $n$-vertex graph in $O^*(2^{n/2})\subset O(1.415^n)$”

Comment: Thanks for all your help, pointing to research on perfect matchings would definitely be an "answer" to this question